# Understanding the ValueError: "Invalid numbers" in python

Tags: python, function, exception, valueerror

I have the following question:

Define a function called exce_sum where you return the sum of two arguments
But if both arguments are 0, the function should raise an exception saying "Invalid numbers" 
The exception needs to have the ValueError() class and the return type of the exception must be a string.
Use try and except.

I wrote the following code:

```
def exce_sum(x,y):
    if x==0 and y==0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid numbers")
    try:
        z=x+y
        return(z)
    except:
        return("the return type of the exception must be a string")
```

When I write the function exce_sum(0,0)
I receive the error `ValueError: Invalid numbers` and not `ValueError: "Invalid numbers"`.
However, I do not know how to receive the error ValueError: "Invalid numbers".
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Change this to

```
if x==0 and y==0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid numbers")
```

this

```
if x==0 and y==0:
        raise ValueError('"Invalid numbers"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to print the double quotes anyway :) When exceptions are printed out to console, the message is typically not enclosed in double quotes.

---

The following should do the trick (you had an unnecessary try-except block):

```
def exce_sum(x, y):

    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid numbers") # if you still want the quotes use '"Invalid numbers"'

    z = x + y
    return str(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your questions could be

def exce_sum(num1,num2):

```
try:
    if (num1 == 0 and num2 == 0):
        raise ValueError("Invalid Numbers")
    else:
        return num1 + num2

except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
```

exce_sum(0,0)